# How to copy path animation location and rotation and apply to a specific bone

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes, path

I want a bone to follow a path and copy the actual location and rotation to a specific bone.

When I add a copy location to the bone the location of the bones stays on x=0 y=0 z=0. But I want it to copy the actual location it is in, like if I animated it by hand and the xyz changes.

See gif for example.
I know the cube is not a bone but this is just an example. It still doesn't copy the location to the cube.

[image: no copy of location and rotation see whitebox]

How can I do this with objects and specific bones?

[edit] [solution]
Bake the animation select object/armature -> animation -> bake action and enable visual keying and clear Constraints. For Bake Data choose the one you are appying it to. If bone use bone if object use object.

Comment: Could you please tell where you're struggling? It seems to work fine, but maybe share your file with the bone following the path (and the one that is supposed to copy): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hey thanks for a fast answer.

Currently the cube is following a path but not animating the actual position and rotation of the cube as keyframes

I want to have keyframes of the actual animation it is doing right now.

Fortunately I already found the solution!

I used the bake animation with visual keying enabled on the selected bone/object. Now it made keyframes of the animation! without the need of the path animation.

Comment: you can write your own answer so other could learn from your question too.

Answer (score 1):

Bake the animation select your object/armature in object mode, then go to object -> animation -> bake action and enable visual keying and clear Constraints. For Bake Data choose the one you are applying it to. If it's a bone use bone if you are using an object use object.